# Simplify Month Over Month % Change, 4 Months Moving Average %

Tags: postgresql, performance, join, window-functions, query-performance

**invoice**

```
 created_at | amount | status | 
------------+--------+---------
 2016-06-01 |   50   |   2    |     
 2016-05-30 |   150  |   2    |     
 2016-04-29 |   32   |   2    |     
 2016-03-28 |   24   |   2    |     
 2016-01-27 |   11   |   2    |
```

In the results I want `month`, the SUM of the `amount` with status as 2 Grouped by Month, % Month Over Month change in Sum of `amount`, % Change in Current Sum of Amount over the Past 4 Months.

The result should include month even when the sum `amount` is 0, that's why I had to use generate_series and do a left join.

Here is the query I wrote to get the desired result.

```
SELECT
  month,
  amount,
  Round(100.00 * (amount - last_amount) / NullIf(last_amount, 0), 2) || ' %' AS monthly_delta,
  Round(100.00 * (amount - (Avg(amount) OVER (
    ORDER BY month DESC
    ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 4 FOLLOWING
  ))) / NullIf(Avg(amount) OVER (
    ORDER BY month DESC
    ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 4 FOLLOWING
  ), 0), 2) || ' %' AS "past 4 months moving avg delta"
FROM (
  SELECT 
    Date_Trunc('month', m) AS month,
    Coalesce(Sum(invoice.amount), 0.00) AS amount,
    Lag(Sum(invoice.amount), 1) OVER (ORDER BY Date_Trunc('month', m)) AS last_amount
  FROM Generate_Series(
    Date_Trunc('month', current_date) - interval '2 year',
    Date_Trunc('month', current_date),
    '1 month'
  ) m
  LEFT JOIN invoice
    ON Date_Trunc('month', invoice.created_at) = m
    AND invoice.status = 2
  GROUP BY month
  ORDER BY month DESC
) tt;
```

How can I simplify this query so it's easy to understand ( mainly the 4 month average )

Comment: Not sure yet about simplifying the query itself but adding some indentation to it might make it easier to read/understand.

Comment: Using [Common table expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) usually makes a complex query easier to read and understand. But, as far as I know, in Postgres CTEs affect the query optimizer.

Comment: Using CTE may slow down the query. you should care about that. how about creating function or view ?

Comment: Have you tried selecting one month in one query an joining it 4 times for different months? It would help if the problem is in window functions and nested queries.